# Waf script '1.9.15' and library '1.8.19' do not match

Tags: c++builder, libraries, waf

I am currently working on NDN architecture (one of the ICN architecture) and for that i need ndn-traffic generator module. This module is available on github. You can find it [here](https://github.com/named-data/ndn-traffic-generator).

The prerequisite for ndn-traffic-generator is ndn-cxx which is NDN C++ library. The steps to install these libraries are given in INSTALL.rst file. But when I try to install these libraries i get an error saying "Waf script '2.0.6' and library '1.8.19' do not match".
I have googled about it and i found this [link](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/4515).
I am not able to figure out how to fix this problem any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks!